# Twitter request does not return all followers

Tags: ios, swift, api, request, twitterkit

I am using TwitterKit in orther to show my followers list. So I am using this GET request:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

The problem is it only returns a list of 20 followers. Does anybody of you know how to manage this problem ? I need it to return all of them.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation, this call returns a lost of followers. The default number of the list of followers it return is 20 thus you're getting the 20 contacts only. This API have a parameter called count where you can specify the number of followers you want to retrieve, the maximum is 200.

[image]

However there is a call that can reurn all the IDs for the followers: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

This will return all followers IDs up to 5000 ID, however it will send ID only and not all the information of the followers. here is the documentation for this API: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not noticed!